# Hover animation with js not working

Tags: javascript, animation, hover

Background color should animate when hovering, stop when not hovering. Any clues to why it's not working? JSLint valid.

```
var pixColors = {
init: function() {
   function pixelColors(){
       var color = '#'+(Math.random()*0xCCCCCC<<0).toString(16);
    $('.colorAnim').animate({
    backgroundColor: color
}, 1000, pixelColors);
}
$('.colorAnim').hover(
function(){
pixelColors();
},
function() {
$('.colorAnim').stop(true);
});
}
}
$(document).ready(function() {
    pixColors.init();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Commandrea/WVU24/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Colors can't be animated by default in jQuery. You need [jQuery Color](http://blog.jquery.com/2012/08/24/jquery-color-2-1-0/) or jQuery UI.

Comment: Oh sheesh. I totally overlooked that!! Thanks for saving me more wasted time.