# JS hover animation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

First of all i checked all duplicates below. But i still couldnt figure out how to.
[make animation hover like transition hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31211084/make-animation-hover-like-transition-hover)
[JS hover-like animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42534621/js-hover-like-animation) [Hover animation with js not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13172069/hover-animation-with-js-not-working)
My problem is
I have

```
<a class="tooltip animated fadeIn" href="#" style="margin-left: 30px; font-size: 1.6em; font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed'; -webkit-animation-delay: 1s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */ animation-delay: 1s; ">
                <i class="fa fa-info helper" ></i>  
                <span class="tooltip-content"><span class="tooltip-text"><span class="tooltip-inner"> If you require access to programs, <br /> please contact to your system administrator </span></span></span>
            </a>
```

And i can use hoover functionality with css like below

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Satisfy);
.tooltip {
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    color: #D93742;
}

/* Gap filler */
.tooltip::after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    pointer-events: none;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.tooltip:hover::after {
    pointer-events: auto;
}

/* Tooltip */

.tooltip-content {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 9999;
    width: 400px;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 100%;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 400;
    color: #D93742; /* #fffaf0; */
    background: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 0 0 5px -200px;
    cursor: default;
    pointer-events: none;
    font-family: inherit; /* 'Satisfy', cursive; */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.3s 0.3s;
    transition: opacity 0.3s 0.3s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-content {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
}

.tooltip-content span {
    display: block;
}

.tooltip-text {
    border-bottom: 10px solid #D93742;  /* #fffaf0; */
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
    transform: scale3d(0,1,1);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s 0.3s;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-text {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
    transition-delay: 0s;
    -webkit-transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
    transform: scale3d(1,1,1);
}

.tooltip-inner {
    background: rgba(85,61,61,0.95);
    padding: 5px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
    webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.3s;
    transition: transform 0.3s;
    color: white;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltip-inner {
    -webkit-transition-delay: 0.3s;
    transition-delay: 0.3s;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}

/* Arrow */

.tooltip-content::after {
    content: '';
    bottom: -20px;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
    border-color: transparent;
    border-top-color: #D93742; /* #fffaf0; */
    border-width: 10px;
    margin-left: -10px;
}
```

I would like to do same thing with javascript mouseover(hover) and mouseout.
First my div mustn't show. I have table which has headers like 'th'. If a user hoover on that header i want to show tooltip with my javascript closure like how css way does. Css codes only opening in certain positions. But my js tooltip one must open for specific table headers. I can show tooltip in js way like below but i cant add animate functionality and css changes to this one. How can i do that ?

```
<div id="toolTipContainer"
   style="z-index:100;  font-size: 1.2em; color: #D93742; border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; width: 200px; height: 80px; position:absolute; display:none;">
    <span class="tooltiptable-content"><span class="tooltiptable-text"><span class="tooltiptable-inner"> If you require access to modules, <br/> please contact to your system administrator </span></span></span>
</div>
```

my script :

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $('th').mouseover(function () {

                if ($(this).index() === 0) {
                    return;
                } else {

                    const top = $(this).offset().top - 82;
                    //   var left = $(this).offset().left;
                    const left = $(this).offset().left;

                    $('#toolTipContainer').css({'top': top, 'left': left, 'width': $(this).width()});
                    $('.tooltiptable-content').css({'width': $(this).width()});


                    //show tool tips
                    $('#toolTipContainer').show();
                }

            });

            $('th').mouseout(function () {
                $("#toolTipContainer").hide();
            });

            $('#toolTipContainer').mouseover(function () {
                $('#toolTipContainer').show();
            });

            $('#toolTipContainer').mouseout(function () {
                $('#toolTipContainer').hide();
            });


        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I can show tooltip in js way like below but i cant add animate functionality and css changes to this one. How can i do that ?

You can use the jQuery `fadeIn()` method instead of `show()` and `fadeOut()` instead of `hide()` to add transitions. If you need more control over the animation there's `animate()`.

Docs:

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

http://api.jquery.com/animate/